# How to declare an __stdcall function pointer

Tags: c++, visual-c++, function-pointers, calling-convention

I tried this

```
typedef void (* __stdcall MessageHandler)(const Task*);
```

This compiles but gives me this warning (VS2003):

> warning C4229: anachronism used :
>   modifiers on data are ignored

I want to declare a pointer to a function with stdcall calling convention? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Invert the `__stdcall` and the `*`.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

As [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), the correct way to write this is

```
typedef void (__stdcall *MessageHandler)(const Task*);
```