# Function pointer for socket io functions send() and recv()

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, sockets, function-pointers, winsock

So I have a function called sockio() that takes a function pointer for either the send() or recv() functions in Winsock 1.1 but I get an error when I try to pass either as an argument of my function pointer type iofunc, defined below.

I can't seem to make them match up so that it'll let me pass in send() or recv(), why is this?

```
// my function pointer typedef
typedef int (*iofunc)(SOCKET, const char*, size_t, int); 

// sockio function prototype
static int sockio(int socket, sockio_buf* buf, iofunc io);
```

Heres the error it gives me when I try to compile in Visual C++ 2010:

```
1>c:\...\sockio.c(24): error C2440: 'function':
  cannot convert from 'int (__stdcall *)(SOCKET,const char *,int,int)' to 'iofunc'
1>c:\...\sockio.c(24):
  warning C4024: 'sockio': different types for formal and actual parameter 3
```

All the parameters look the same to me. Is it anything to do with the (__stdcall *) bit?

Comment: can you show the c code you are compiling ?

Comment: I don't know whether that's the only problem, but yes, the function pointer will need to be declared as stdcall.

Comment: Yup, that fixed it, thanks Harry

Used this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298394/how-to-declare-an-stdcall-function-pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `typedef` is missing a calling convention, so C's default calling convention (usually `__cdecl`) is used instead.  `send()` and `recv()` use the `__stdcall` calling convention:

```
typedef int (__stdcall *iofunc)(SOCKET, const char*, size_t, int);
```