# typedef a function pointer type

Tags: c, function, pointers, typedef

I want to declare a pointer type which point to a function, so I try:

`typedef void (*print)(void);`  works perfect

`void (*print)(void);`   p is a ponter variable , not a type.

`typedef (void) (*print)(void);` error expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘void’

`typedef void (*)(void) Print;`

error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘_ *attribute* _’ before ‘Print’ .

My question is:

1. Do I have to use `typedef` to declare a function pointer type ?
2. Why `typedef (void) (*print)(void);` is wrong ? what `()` means here?
3. Why I can't write in this way:`typedef void (*)(void) Print` ?

Comment: You don't need typedef to declare a function pointer typer.

Comment: How to do it ? post the idea ,please.

Comment: All your questions can pretty much be answered with "because the language designers decided it that way"

Comment: In an answer to another question, I tried to explain how to declare a function pointer. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6905987/396551

Answer (score 10):

The correct way is:

```
typedef void (*print_function_ptr)(void)
```

and its usage for variable/parameter declaration is:

```
print_function_ptr p;
```

1. You don't need a typedef to declare a variable. You can directly write `void (*p)(void)` to declare a variable `p` pointing to a function taking `void` and returning `void`. However to declare a type alias / name for a pointer to function, `typedef` is the tool.
2. It does not mean anything it is not a valid C syntax.
3. Because it is not how C works. Typedefs in C mimics how variables are declared or defined.

Comment: I hope declare a function pointer type , not a variable, is there a way to do this without typedef?

Comment: @LidongGuo: what do you mean by 'declare a function pointer type'?  You can declare an object that is of type 'pointer to function' without using a `typedef`.  There is no way other than using `typedef` to create a type name that you can use subsequently.

Comment: I hope to declare a type like a struct name, then I can use it declare lots of function pointer'

Comment: @LidongGuo then this answer shows you how to do that. After the typedef, you can just do this to have 5 function pointers with the same signature: `print_function_ptr p1, p2, p3, p4, p5;`

Answer (score 3):

1. No, you don't have to use a `typedef` to create an object of type 'pointer to function':

   ```
   void somefunc(void (*pointer)(void))
   {
       (*pointer)();
       pointer();
   }
   ```

   However, there is no way to create a name for a type other than by using a `typedef`.  I suppose you could indulge in macro hackery to generate a 'pointer to function', but after the macro is expanded, you'd have a 'pointer to function' written out:

   ```
   #define PTR_FUNC(func) void (*func)(void)
   void somefunc(PTR_FUNC(pointer)) { ... }
   ```
2. The `(void)` notation as the type name is wrong.  You don''t write: `(int) x;` and expect to declare a variable `x` -— it is a type cast.  Same with the notation you're using in your `typedef`.
3. You can't write `typedef void (*)(void) Print;` because it is not an allowed C syntax.  You also can't write `typedef [32] int name;` either — it isn't valid C syntax.