# How does typedef-ing a block works

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, typedef

In C/Obj-C, we do a typedef like this `typedef int MYINT;` which is clear.

Doing typedef for a block -`typedef void (^MyBlock) (int a);`

Now, we can use `MyBlock`.

Shouldn't it be like - `typedef void (^MyBlock) (int a) MyBlock;` similar to `#define`?

How the syntax works?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

See [Declaring a Block Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxDeclaringCreating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH4-SW3) in "Blocks Programming Topics":

> Block variables hold references to blocks. You declare them using
>   syntax similar to that you use to declare a pointer to a function,
>   except that you use ^ instead of *.

So

```
 typedef void (^myBlock) (int a);
```

defines a the type of a block using the same syntax as

```
 typedef void (*myFunc) (int a);
```

declares a function pointer.

See e.g. [Understanding typedefs for function pointers in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591361/understanding-typedefs-for-function-pointers-in-c-examples-hints-and-tips-ple) for more information about function pointers.

Answer (score 28):

Also from "Blocks Programming Topics", creating a type for blocks should be like this:

```
typedef returnType (^blockName)(argument1, argument2, ...)
```

Below is a very simple practical example:

```
typedef float (^MyBlockType)(float, float);
MyBlockType AddTwoFloat = ^(float a, float b) {return a + b;};
MyBlockType MultiplyTwoFloat = ^(float a, float b) {return a * b;};
float c = AddTwoFloat(1, 2); //c = 3
float d = MultiplyTwoFloat(1, 2); //d = 2
```