# Declaring typedef to a function

Tags: c

How does the following code works without giving a name for the typedef in the 3rd line?How compiler assumes pf as a new data type?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fun(int, int);
typedef int (*pf) (int, int);
int proc(pf, int, int);

int main(){
    printf("%d\n", proc(fun, 6, 6));
    return 0;
}

int fun(int a, int b){
    return (a==b);
}

int proc(pf p, int a, int b){
    return ((*p)(a, b));
}
```

Comment: pf is the name of the Pointer to the Function ;)

Comment: I think the question here is *what are the rules* for what typedef considers the alias.  IOW, `typedef int int32` considers int32 the alias.  What are the rules that in the function typedef above that the 2nd of 4 parameters is considered the alias?

Comment: if you write `typedef int* name` then `name` is the alias for the type (`int*`), in the case of a function pointer it just looks a bit more complicated but it is the same principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntactically, `typedef` is treated as storage class specifier, like `extern` or `static`. It doesn't actually specify a storage class; it's just defined that way for convenience. So you can replace `typedef` by `static` and get a declaration with a different meaning, but similar syntax, and defining the same identifier.

You have:

```
typedef int (*pf) (int, int);
```

Replacing `typedef` by `static` gives:

```
static int (*pf) (int, int);
```

which declares a function pointer named `pf`. The `typedef` version of the declaration also declares the identifier `pf`, but as a type name, not as a pointer object.

Keep in mind that `typedef` doesn't create a new type, merely a new name for an existing type. Rather than declaring `pf` as an object, the `typedef` declaration makes `pf` an alias for the type name `int (*)(int, int)`.

Since storage class specifiers are optional, you can also understand a complex `typedef` declaration by dropping the word `typedef`:

```
int (*pf) (int, int);
```

which declares `pf` as an object of type `int (*) (int, int)`.

You can also use the `cdecl` program to explain complex declarations like this. It doesn't understand `typedef` (as of version 2.5), but you can just drop the `typedef` keyword:

```
$ cdecl
Type `help' or `?' for help
cdecl> explain typedef int (*pf) (int, int);
syntax error
cdecl> explain int (*pf) (int, int);
declare pf as pointer to function (int, int) returning int
cdecl>
```

If you don't have the `cdecl` program installed on your system, there's an online version at http://cdecl.org/

Answer (score 7):

It does give it a name:

```
 typedef int (*pf) (int, int);
               ^^
```

That's the typedef'd name. It reads as: *pf is a pointer to a function that takes two ints and returns an int*.

For more details on how function pointer typedefs work, see:

- [Understanding typedefs for function pointers in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591361/understanding-typedefs-for-function-pointers-in-c-examples-hints-and-tips-ple)
- [The function pointer tutorial](http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html)

Answer (score 2):

`pf` acts as an alias for a function which takes two `int`s as argument and returns an `int`.

It is a function pointer.

Answer (score 1):

`pf` as typedef is a type definition ; it defines the signature of a function (what to provide as arguments and what it will return).
For the function `proc` using `p` as a variable; it defines the 'contract' when executing this function at address `p` ; this contract can only be checked at compile time, because basically at runtime the `p` variable is only an address.

Answer (score 0):

The typedef declaration has got a name -- 'pf'. And it represents a function pointer (instead of pointing to data, it points to executable code in memory).

When declaring function pointers, typedef does not follow the (usual) pattern -- "typedef oldTypeName newAliasName". Rather, the alias name (i.e. pf in above example) appears in between the return type (on left) and the argument types (on right).