# What does these two arguments mean in typedef?

Tags: c, function, typedef

I have a piece of code and I don't understand that one `typedef`:

```
typedef void (inst_cb_t) (const char*, size_t);
```

Doesn't that actually mean you can use `inst_cb_t` as a `void` now? But what about the stuff in the second brackets?

Comment: May find [this interesting](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=void+%28inst_cb_t%29+%28const+char*%2C+size_t%29%3B)

Comment: No, that's a typedef for a function pointer. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591361/understanding-typedefs-for-function-pointers-in-c-examples-hints-and-tips-ple

Comment: @inetknght that's a typedef for a function, not for a function pointer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The declaration

```
typedef void (inst_cb_t) (const char*, size_t);
```

defines `inst_cb_t` as a function that takes two arguments of type `const char*` and `size_t` and returns `void`.

One interesting part of this declaration is that you can use this only in function declaration and pointer to function deceleration.

```
inst_cb_t foo;
```

You can't use it in function definition like

```
inst_cb_t foo      // WRONG
{
    // Function body
}
```

Look at C standard:

#### C11: 6.9.1 Function definitions:

> The identifier declared in a function definition (which is the name of the function) shall have a function type, as specified by the declarator portion of the function definition.<sup>162)</sup>

and footnote 162 is

> The intent is that the type category in a function definition cannot be inherited from a `typedef`:
>
> ```
> typedef int F(void);              // type F is ‘‘function with no parameters
>                                   // returning int’’
> F f, g;                           // f and g both have type compatible with F
> F f { /* ... */ }                 // WRONG: syntax/constraint error
> F g() { /* ... */ }               // WRONG: declares that g returns a function
> int f(void) { /* ... */ }         // RIGHT: f has type compatible with F
> int g() { /* ... */ }             // RIGHT: g has type compatible with F
> F *e(void) { /* ... */ }          // e returns a pointer to a function
> F *((e))(void) { /* ... */ }      // same: parentheses irrelevant
> int (*fp)(void);                  // fp points to a function that has type F
> F *Fp;                            // Fp points to a function that has type F
> ```