# How to accomplish simulation of nested function in ANSI C where i can dynamicaly update my functions? pls look at whole explanation

Tags: python, ansi-c

I am new to this community and I would like to ask one question. I am not programer/developer but I use programing to accelerate my scientific computes. In past i have used a lot python, but now because of my new jobs I need to use C programing language. I am new and it is kinda dificult but i struggle :D. My main question is, how to accomplish this kind of code from python to C:

```
def foo(x,a):
    def en(x):
        return a*x
    return en
```

I use this to get dynamicaly final equations and i can write my solvers for lot of diferent examples. Basicaly i want to do same thing in C. Because ansi C does not support nested functions i can't get it with typdefs or just can't figure out how to do it. I have searched a lot for answer but i haven't found it.

Thanks in advance. 
PS sorry for my bad english if it is :D

EDIT: i forgot to add my sample code from where i tried to do same thing :D but i got error because ansi C does not supprt nested fucntions

```
double fun(double x, double a){
return a*x-5;
}
double n(double x);
typedef double (*function)(double);
function wrapper(double x, double a){
    function ptr;
    double functionReturn(double x){
        return fun(a,x);
    }
    ptr = functionReturn;
    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: This is somewhat more difficult in a low-level language such as C.  Functions aren't first-class citizens in C.  They can't be created dynamically, and can't be passed around like other objects.  You will have to use different techniques instead, like using an opaque pointer.  (I know that's not really helpful yet, which is why this is a comment, not an answer.)

Comment: [See how this problem is handled in the GNU Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Providing-the-function-to-solve.html#Providing-the-function-to-solve).

Comment: i am very thankful to any pointer towards my solution! thx

Comment: maybe interesting? [Understanding typedefs for function pointers in C: Examples, hints and tips, please](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591361/understanding-typedefs-for-function-pointers-in-c-examples-hints-and-tips-ple). You cannot nest functions but you can use pointers to them which will allow do do what you want? Also look at the **Linked** questions on the right-hand side of that page?

Comment: both answers gave me a lot of useful material to think about, and i think i kinda see my escape! i will left this question still open for a while(point me if i am wrong but i can close or open my questions right?) but i think this answers really helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can not produce functions on the fly in C. Therefore, your approach will need to be quite different, and how you adapt it will depend on the details of what you are trying to accomplish. I'll show two ways to maybe replace function returning function behavior.

## Approach 1: If you only need to use 1 returned function at a time.

Typically, if you are computing functions on the fly, functions returned from a given function will be very similar to eachother. You can use static data storage to get this effect, supposing you only need one valid returned function at a time.

```
static double fun_a;

double fun( double x )
{
   return fun_a*x - 5;
}

void wrapper( double a )
{
   fun_a = a;
}
```

In your example, you have a 2 argument function 'fun' and you want a function that returns functions which are given by the slice of fun given by fixing one argument. When you call 'wrapper(a)', 'fun' essentially changes such that calling 'fun(x)' is the same as calling 'fun(x,a)' (associating the second argument 'a' with the static variable 'fun_a').

Basically, rather than returning a function, 'wrapper' changes an existing function into what it would have returned (and does not actually return anything). So you get the same effect, you just only can use one return at a time.

If you take a moment to think about situations where you want to calculate a function, you will probably see that it is almost always fairly straightforward to instead define a function that uses global variables, and get your desired function by modifying those global variables.

Note that the global variables are accessible from other parts of the program, be careful about how you name them to avoid them being messed with elsewhere. If I have a function 'fun' and I define something globabl to go along with it, I usually name it 'fun_[something]', so that it is easy to avoid such problems.

Finally, if you have any small fixed limit to how many functions you need to use at once, you can acheive your goal by doing something like this:

```
static double fun1_a;

double fun1( double x )
{
   return a*x - 5;
}

void wrapper1( double a )
{
   fun1_a = a;
}



static double fun2_a;

double fun2( double x )
{
   return a*x - 5;
}

void wrapper2( double a )
{
   fun2_a = a;
}

.
.
.
```

## Approach 2: Use a typedef

The example you gave is very simple, I am guessing because your situation is too complex to ask this question in actual context. This second approach requires a little more complex of an example to make sense.

Say you have a function E(x,m) that calculates how many prime factors x and m have in common. This is a potentially very expensive function, so you might want to calculate a function F_k(m) that calculates how many prime factors k and m have in common, as that would be a drastically faster function. Note that E takes variable x, whereas k is fixed for F_k, so the functions serve different roles.

This is just an arbitrary example to demonstrate a technique for doing this sort of thing in a situation that is more complex than simply taking a slice of a higher arity function.

You can do something like:

```
typedef long long unsigned llu;
typedef llu* F_type;

int fun( F_type L, llu m )
{
   int i, j=0;
   for(i=0; L[i]; ++i)
      if( m % L[i] == 0 ) ++j;
   return j;
}

F_type wrapper( llu k )
{
   // code that returns an array listing the primes dividing k, followed by 0
}
```

So, rather than calling some function that returns F_k for a given k, you can simply call wrapper(k), set the result to L, and call fun(L,m). Then L serves the role of the function F_k, by essentially converting fun to F_k.

This approach has the advantage that any number of such types may be active in the program at a given moment.

The real answer to your question is that you just need to restructure your approach to use data types that can be constructed during execution. I hope these two examples can help illustrate some of the ways to do that in C.