# How to forward declare a function that takes a pointer to a function as a parameter?

Tags: c, forward-declaration

How do I forward declare a function that has a function as a parameter in C?

Here is the function:

```
void start_thread (void* function (void*)) {

    ...

}
```

I tried forward declaring it as:

```
void start_thread (void*);
```

as well as:

```
void start_thread (void* (void*));
```

and:

```
void start_thread (void*, void*);
```

None of these were accepted.  What is the correct day to forward declare for this function?

Edit:

```
void start_thread (void (*) (void*));
```

Yields:

```
Compilation error
prog.c: At top level:
prog.c:135:6: error: conflicting types for 'start_thread'
 void start_thread (void* function (void*)) {
      ^
prog.c:25:6: note: previous declaration of 'start_thread' was here
 void start_thread (void (*) (void *));
      ^
```

Comment: `void (*)(void *)`. The rest can be found in a C book of your choice.

Comment: What Olaf said. If you want to supply a name for tha function (for documentation purposes): `void (*functionName)(void *);` You were almost there chodobaggins, only missing one set of parenthesis.

Comment: typedef is your friend, and this is my favorite answer to a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591361/understanding-typedefs-for-function-pointers-in-c

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The correct forward declaration/prototype would be:

```
void start_thread(void*(void*);
```

Comment: It looks like you forgot to correct an earlier or later declaration in the code you are attempting to compile after you received the correct prototype from the comment and the two answers. Please  See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: Actually not true, those answers were incorrect; the answer I posted is the one that compiles correctly.

Comment: Did you try it?  Or are you just saying that and downvoting my answer based on your expectation?.  My code compiled exactly as above and ran perfectly.

Comment: @ClintonJ Your parentheses are mismatched. Did _you_ try it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the windscreen wiper technique (left-right-left...):

It's a pointer, so there is an `*`. On a function, so `(*)`.

It return `void`, so,  `void (*)`.

It take a `void*`, so `void (*)(void*)`

The prototype is `void start_thread(void (*)(void*));`

Comment: Compilation error
prog.c: At top level:
prog.c:135:6: error: conflicting types for 'start_thread'
 void start_thread (void* function (void*)) {
      ^
prog.c:25:6: note: previous declaration of 'start_thread' was here
 void start_thread (void (*) (void *));

Comment: There is an extra `*` (or you missed an `*`) in the return type

Answer (score 0):

For the function definition you have:

```
void start_thread (void* function (void*)) {
```

The argument is a function which accepts a `void *` as a parameter and returns a `void *`.  To be more clear about the definition, it should be:

```
void start_thread (void *(*function)(void*)) {
```

So the declaration should be:

```
void start_thread (void *(*)(void*));
```