# Inlining typedef for a function returning a function

Tags: c, typedef

Is it possible to inline the return signature of a function that returns a function?

**Working version**

**typedef return function signature**

```
typedef void (*ptrFunc)(int);
```

**function defined in a struct**

```
struct Observer {
    ptrFunc (*getMethod)(struct Test *test);
};
```

**Attempt to Inline:**

```
struct Observer {
    (void (*test)(int)) (*getMethod)(struct Test *test);
};
```

Comment: Review [Understanding typedefs for function pointers in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591361/).  A major question is: are you sure you want to inline the definition?  It is typically a lot easier to handle the declarations with judicious typedefs for the function pointers.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler

Comment: You can use 'cdecl`

Comment: Just use the typedef version. The C syntax for returning function pointers or array pointers from functions is unreadable and should not be used.

Comment: Btw "inlining" means something completely different, it can either refer to when a compiler optimizes a function call by placing all machine code of the function in the caller, or it can refer to including assembler code inside the C code. The correct term here would be _obfuscate_, which means taking readable code and turning it unreadable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions can't return functions. But yes, you can have a function pointer that returns a function pointer, without using a typedef

Here's the trick for navigating these kinds of types:

1. You'll notice that `ptrFunc (*getMethod)(struct Test *test);` looks like a variable declaration `ptrFunc someVar;`. Except that instead of `someVar` our "variable" has the funny name `(*getMethod)(struct Test *test)`.
2. If you wanted to declare a variable `someVar` of type `ptrFunc` without using a typedef, you'd write `void (*someVar)(int);`
3. Therefore, if you wanted to declare a variable `(*getMethod)(struct Test *test)` of type `ptrFunc`, you'd write `void (*(*getMethod)(struct Test *test))(int);`.

   See how that works? I just changed `someVar` to `(*getMethod)(struct Test *test)`.
4. We can double-check this using a tool like [cdecl.org](https://cdecl.org/?q=void+%28*%28*getMethod%29%28struct+Test+*%29%29%28int%29%3B) (note - cdecl doesn't like the `test` parameter having a name).

By the way, this trick also works with other types - for example, pointers to functions that return pointers to arrays of pointers to functions.

But seriously, just use the typedef to preserve your own sanity.

Addendum:

If you want to put `void (*(*getMethod)(struct Test *test))(int);` in a structure then you write it as:

```
struct Observer {
    void (*(*getMethod)(struct Test *test))(int);
};
```

... but I'm sure you were smart enough to work that out.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question before a bit but i think you missed the udpates, can you please update your answer. see the struct observer, a param test was added. `ptrFunc (*getMethod)(struct Test *test);`

Comment: @Developer: Insert `struct Test *` between each occurrence of `()` in the answer.

Comment: and if you can write the full declaration of `structure Observer` in the answer, that'd help a lot. Appreciate your answer.

Comment: @Developer: And don't be lazy; immibis wrote out the hard part of the declaration; you can add `struct Observer {` before and `};` after that line!

Comment: i'm a little confused and have been mixed up that's why asking for a declaration

Comment: @Developer Done, but as I said, I'm sure you were smart enough to work that out. Stack Overflow isn't an excuse to turn off your brain.

Comment: thanks, I've been trying different things, but this one is very different and you are smart. I'm going to break it down for understanding and test it out. will comment in a while in any case.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it as well. Your approach `void (*someVar)(int);` helped me a lot, is there an official documentation that gives off such knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `cdecl` program to translate English into C. [Available online too](https://cdecl.org/?q=declare+getMethod+as+pointer+to+function+%28pointer+to+struct+test%29+returning+pointer+to+function+%28int%29+returning+void):

```
cdecl> declare getMethod as pointer to function (pointer to struct test) returning pointer 
       to function (int) returning void;
void (*(*getMethod)(struct test *))(int )
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend cdecl. `void (*(*getMethod)(struct test *))(int );`= syntax error. `void func (void)` = syntax error (come on...). `static void (*(*getMethod)(struct test *))(int )`= "declare getMethod as static pointer to function" Err... what!? `inline void (*(*getMethod)(struct test *))(int )` = syntax error. `void (*(*getMethod)(struct test *restrict))(int )` syntax error. And so on. It is simply a bad, outdated tool.

Comment: @Lundin it is *`explain`* `void (*(*getMethod)(struct test *))(int );`