# how do I understand typedef int (*ibm_ldap_search_s)(LDAP *, char *, int , char *, char * [],int , LDAPMessage **)

Tags: c

When I review a C program , I saw some code like this :

```
typedef int (*ibm_ldap_search_s)(LDAP *, char *, int , char *, char * [],int , LDAPMessage **);
```

What does this mean?

Comment: have a look at https://cdecl.org/

Comment: Its a typedef for a function pointer. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591361/understanding-typedefs-for-function-pointers-in-c).

Comment: this creates a type alias called `ibm_ldap_search_s`, aliased to "pointer to function returning `int` and accepting the  specified parameters as arguments. Judging by the name, it's used as a callback or a dynamic lookup  within a library.

Answer (score 0):

The constructions like `rettype (* name )( arguments... )` are used for function pointers.

`int (* f1 )(void);`

`f1` is a function pointer which takes no arguments and returns int.

`typedef int (*ibm_ldap_search_s)(LDAP *, char *, int , char *, char * [],int , LDAPMessage **);`

`ibm_ldap_search_s` is a aliased type (ie. typedef). It aliases a function pointer which takes arguments: (pointer to LDAP, pointer to char, int value, pointer to char, pointer to pointer to char, int value and pointer to pointer to LDAPMessage) and returns an int. `[]` in function declarations is equal to `*`, i mean `char *[]` is the same as `char **`.
Example:

```
typedef int (*ibm_ldap_search_s)(LDAP *, char *, int , char *, char * [],int , LDAPMessage **);

int ibm_ldap_search(LDAP *ldap, char *str1, int value1, 
                    char *str2, char *pointer_to_strings[], 
                    int value2, LDAPMEssages **messages) { 
    return 0; 
}

int main() {
   ibm_ldap_search_s bar = ibm_ldap_search;
   int value = bar(NULL, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, 2, NULL);
   printf("Function returned $d\n", value);
   return 0;
 }
```