# function typedef and call to function from struct in C

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I'm trying to figure out the following code.
Especially the part that relates to the function typedef.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void foo1(int var1, int var2); // foo1 decleration
typedef void (foo2)(int var1, int var2); // what is this exactly?

typedef struct somestruct{
    foo2* somefunc;
}SOMESTRUCT;

int main()
{
    SOMESTRUCT struct1;
    struct1.somefunc = &foo1; 
    struct1.somefunc(1,5);
    return 0;
}

void foo1(int var1, int var2){
    printf("this is function inside struct var1 = %d var2 = %d",var1, var2);
}
```

Comment: typedef creates a type SOMESTRUCT.  You declare an instance struct1.  You set the function in struct1 and then call it.

Comment: The answer beneith this post might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591361/understanding-typedefs-for-function-pointers-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line...

```
typedef void (foo2)(int var1, int var2); // what is this exactly?
```

...declares a new type, `foo2`, as a function that takes two `int` parameters and returns void.

Later in the code, the address of function `foo1` (which matches the function signature) is stored in the `somefunc` member of `struct1`, and then it's called. with parameters 1 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

Tim Randall's explanation is pretty good but let me add this.

The `typedef` keyword defines a new data type that can be used in place of its original definitions.  If you did not want to use `typedef`, the structure could have been defined as:

```
typedef struct somestruct{
    void(*somefunc)(int a,int b);
}SOMESTRUCT;
```

In this case, we don't save much but if we had more than one function pointer, the use of the `typedef` saves quite a bit and makes the program easier to read.