# Postgres typedef TupleTableSlot *(*ExecProcNodeMtd) (struct PlanState *pstate)

Tags: postgresql, pointers, struct, typedef

In `postgres` source code, I'm confused with the code as below.

`typedef TupleTableSlot *(*ExecProcNodeMtd) (struct PlanState *pstate);`

Can any one explain it, thank you.

Comment: It's a type alias for a [function pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer#Example_in_C) (named `ExecProcNodeMtd`, expecting a `PlanState *` and returning a `TupleTableSlot *`).

Comment: Yes, I get it. Thank you.

Comment: This explains well, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591361/understanding-typedefs-for-function-pointers-in-c