# sighandler_t typedef statement in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, signals, typedef

While studying Signals in Linux, I came across this declaration :

```
typedef void (*sighandler_t)(int);
sighandler_t signal (int signo, sighandler_t handler);
```

The handler function must return `void` and its prototype has the form :

```
void my_handler (int signo);
```

Linux uses a `typedef`, `sighandler_t`, to define this prototype.

When I saw Linux Man pages for `signal()` function it is present there.

But I don't understand What that `typedef` statement here means.

Can anyone explain what that `typedef sighandler_t` means?

Comment: It's just giving a name (`sighandler_t`) to the otherwise unnamed (function) type (`void(*)(int)`). Like `typedef struct { double x, y; } point;` gives the name `point` to the untagged (and unnamed) struct.

Comment: See also [Understanding typedefs for function pointers in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591361/understanding-typedefs-for-function-pointers-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of C magic that says the following:

```
typedef void (*sighandler_t)(int);
```

> there is a special type called `sighandler_t` that is a pointer to a function that takes an integer argument and returns nothing.

```
sighandler_t signal(int signo, sighandler_t handler);
```

> there is a function `signal` that takes an integer named `signo` and a function pointer `handler` as arguments and returns a function pointer.

The `typedef` literally means "type definition" and is used to define a placeholder for complex types — like function pointers or structures etc.

The definition of a function pointer is a bit beyond the scope of this question, but can be thought of as a command that the user writes, that the framework will call, without knowing exactly what that function will be.