# how to use typeof of function to create another function with the same type

Tags: c, function, typeof

for example:

```
int f(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

typeof(f) f2
{
    return -f(a, b);
}
```

Is something like this possible in C?

Edit: The reason I'm asking this is I'm trying to do something like:

```
#define MAKE_NEGATION_OF(function) \
typeof(function) function##_negated { \
    return -function(a, b); \
}
```

Comment: What is the actual and underlying problem you need to solve? Why do you need something like this?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I want use a macro to generate a function with the same type, but different return.

Comment: Could you be more clear, please? The first example shows `sum()` and `difference()`. The second example is trivially `0 - function( a, b );` that could be handled by a wrapping function called `function_negated()`...

Comment: Ah, a moving target is hard to hit...

Comment: And why do you want such a macro? What is the problem that's supposed to solve? I'm sorry, but your question is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The problem IS that I want to generate a negated version of a function. Look at the "Edit:"

Comment: And why not just  a simple function-like macro for that? Like `#define negate_function(function, ...) (-((function)(__VA_ARGS__)))`? Or, to make it very  clear what's happening, just call the original function explicitly with the negation? Why do you need to hide it behind another function that does just the negation? It doesn't really make the code cleaner or more maintainable.

Comment: And while you said why you want a macro, to "generate" a "negated version", you haven't told us about the problem that's supposed to solve? Why do you need to "generate" such a function? What is the *original* problem that's supposed to solve? What is the actual use-case? What specific part of the design, requirement analysis, requirements themselves, does that help solving? Always ask about that underlying problem directly, and we can better help you solve that instead of hacking on your predetermined solution (which might not be the only one, or even the best one).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude because I need a function pointer to the negated function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want use a macro to generate a function with the same type, but different return.

Note that your two examples (used to) differ (before the question was edited).

Given the previous *typeof* example, you could instead write a macro that generates functions with the same signature, differing only by key tokens:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DEFINE_BINARY_OPERATION(name, op) \
    int name(int a, int b) { \
        return a op b; \
    }

DEFINE_BINARY_OPERATION(add, +)
DEFINE_BINARY_OPERATION(subtract, -)

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", add(5, 6));
    printf("%d\n", subtract(5, 6));
}
```

```
11
-1
```

Given the *macro* example, there is no need for another function, just negate the function call in a macro wrapper.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define add_negated(...) (-add(__VA_ARGS__))

int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", add(5, 6));
    printf("%d\n", add_negated(5, 6));
}
```

```
11
-11
```

If you *need* a function pointer, then this is an extremely rigid combination of both ideas, which does not scale well at all. If your actual use case is non-trivial, you should probably just write the functions and their signatures by hand.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DEFINE_BINARY_EXPRESSION(name, expr) \
    int name(int a, int b) { \
        return expr; \
    }
#define NEGATE_BINARY_EXPRESSION(name) \
    DEFINE_BINARY_EXPRESSION(name##_negated, -name(a, b))

DEFINE_BINARY_EXPRESSION(add, a + b)
NEGATE_BINARY_EXPRESSION(add)

DEFINE_BINARY_EXPRESSION(subtract, a - b)
NEGATE_BINARY_EXPRESSION(subtract)

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", add(5, 6));
    printf("%d\n", add_negated(5, 6));

    printf("%d\n", subtract(5, 6));
    printf("%d\n", subtract_negated(5, 6));
}
```

```
11
-11
-1
1
```

Comment: the ```add_negated``` macro you made wont work for me, I need a function pointer to the negated function

Answer (score 1):

Functions cannot be created with a `typedef` or `typeof` expression, because such types do not contain any information regarding the names of parameters, and a function definition requires names for its parameters.

While you can *declare* a function with a `typedef` or `typeof`, you can't *define* one that way.

Answer (score 0):

In C, you cannot directly create a new function with the same type as another function using a `typeof` construct or a similar mechanism like you can in some other languages.

However, you can achieve a relatively similar functionality by using function pointers and defining a new function that has the same signature (parameter types and return type) as an existing function. Here's an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

int subtract(int a, int b) {
    return a - b;
}

int main() {
    // Define a function pointer type with the same signature as 'add'
    typedef int (*BinaryIntFunction)(int, int);

    // Create a function pointer variable and assign 'add' to it
    BinaryIntFunction operation = add;

    // Use the function pointer to call 'add'
    int result = operation(5, 3);
    printf("Result: %d\n", result); // Output: Result: 8

    // Assign 'subtract' to the same function pointer variable
    operation = subtract;

    // Use the function pointer to call 'subtract'
    result = operation(5, 3);
    printf("Result: %d\n", result); // Output: Result: 2

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This `typedef` hides the _pointer nature_ of `operation`... No recommended...

Comment: @Fe2O3 `typedef`ing function pointers is a generally accepted use case, as the syntax quickly gets unwieldy. Functions already hide their "pointer nature" - nothing about `int add(int a, int a)` or `add(1, 2)` says *pointer* any more than `operation(5, 3)` *doesn't*. Really, the only time you do notice is when you *don't* `typedef`. Compare [`sighandler_t signal(int signum, sighandler_t handler);`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) with [`void (*signal(int sig, void (*handler)(int)))(int);`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/signal).

Comment: @Oka Would you be so kind as to rewrite the last comparison using a `typedef` but omit the splats from the `typedef`? My brain is going woozy... Seems to me it would be something like: `sighandler_t *signal( int signum, sighandler_t *handler );` making its _pointer nature_ more apparent. (People who code this low level are miles beyond my ability.) :-)

Comment: @Fe2O3 `typedef void sighandler_t(int);` should work with your example, but it is very uncommon in my experience - sort of splitting the difference, as it were. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59030387/2505965).

Comment: @Oka Thanks... It's the mention: "Cannot be used interchangeably" that makes me favour "showing the splats" when declaring things... Common or not, splats can be comforting... A bit of typographic reassurance in these crazy times... `:-)`