# what is this typedef achieveing in cpython/Include/object.h

Tags: python, c, cpython

Normally what a typedef does is

`typedef DATATYPE NEW_NAME`

However, the following is a bit complex and seems like mixing with some other concepts (like the tuple-alike guy)

`typedef PyObject *(*newfunc)(struct _typeobject *, PyObject *, PyObject *);`

Comment: Please don't post images of text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding typedefs for function pointers in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591361/understanding-typedefs-for-function-pointers-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

The definition looks confusing since function pointers are confusing at first. The definition

```
typedef PyObject *(*newfunc)(struct _typeobject *, PyObject *, PyObject *);
```

Means “create a typedef named `newfunc` that is a function taking in a `struct _typeobject*` and two `PyObject*`s and returns a `PyObject*`. The name is after the return type in the middle like it would be with a regular function definition:

```
PyObject *somefunc(struct _typeobject *, PyObject *, PyObject *);
```

As it’s a function pointer it needs parentheses and another * to show it is a pointer and the datatype is around the name.

Comment: why do we need (*newfunc) instead of newfunc?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen so the syntax for function typedef is different to data type typedef? becuz here we're like defining a variable which accept a function as its value, and this function's prototype must match the type's definition