# Confused from the declaration of the signal function

Tags: c, signals

I'm not sure how exactly to read this:

```
void (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int))) (int);
```

I know that `void (*func)(int)` is a pointer to a function accepting int and returning void.

My best guess is: signal is a function accepting int, and `void (*func)(int)`, which returns a pointer to a function accepting int and returning void (so another `void (*func)(int)`). I am just a bit confused by this usage, and also the fact that [this website](https://cdecl.org/) is not able to translate it properly.

Comment: You might find [Understanding typedefs for function pointers in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1591361/15168) useful.  I'm even tempted to close this as a duplicate of that.

Comment: I didn't see that @JonathanLeffler and it definitely would have answered me.

Answer (score 2):

Your reading is correct.

The `signal` function takes two arguments, an `int` and a `void (*)(int)` (i.e. a pointer to a function that takes an `int` and returns `void`), and returns a `void (*)(int)`.

As for cdecl, you need to remove the parameter names so it recognizes it as a declaration.  So if you pass it this:

```
void (*signal(int, void (*)(int))) (int);
```

It returns this:

> declare signal as function (int, pointer to function (int) returning void) returning pointer to function (int) returning void

When dealing with function pointers, it makes code more readable to use a `typedef` for them.  In fact, the Linux man page for `signal` defines it as follows:

```
typedef void (*sighandler_t)(int);

sighandler_t signal(int signum, sighandler_t handler);
```

Which is much clearer than the explicit version.